# Error in Win Form Login

Tags: winforms, authentication, combobox

```
     private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         var dt = new DataTable();
         const string Connectionstring = "Data Source=GARETH-PC1;Initial  Catalog=Genres;Integrated Security=True";
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
                var query = "Select Username From Login Where Username ='" + ComboBox1.SelectedText + "' Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
                {

                sda.Fill(dt);
            }

        }

        if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString() == "1")

        {
            Hide();

            var ss = new Main();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
        }
    }
```

The  if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString() == "1") - Returns an error saying there's nothing in the table... But there is ..any suggestions?

Comment: How have you reached the conviction that you have a record?

Comment: Sorry new to programming.

Comment: I have the SQL Tables set up, The columts with test usernames put inside. - But when I run debugger it finds the table but there's nothing inside.

Comment: Never, never do this.  Windows already has a very highly secure login, whatever you add just causes nasty security leakage when users inevitably re-use their password.  You are already using Integrated Security=True, no additional help is required or desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString()
```

This is working for me.

Comment: I meant like: if(dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString()=="1") {...}

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code in this way.
First, change to a parameterized query instead of a string concatenation (Sql Injection and parsing)
Second, use the count property to check if you have found a record or not

```
 private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var dt = new DataTable();
     const string Connectionstring = "Data Source=GARETH-PC1;Initial  Catalog=Genres;Integrated Security=True";
    var query = "Select Username From Login Where Username =@uname AND Password=@pwd";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", ComboBox1.SelectedText);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", textBox2.Text);
        using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Hide();

        var ss = new Main();
        ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
    }
}
```

As a side note, it is a very bad idea to store passwords in plain text inside a database. You should consider to use an HASH and store it instead of the plain password.

Comment: Really a bad idea to flood the site with tons of identical questions. You risk to be banned. But a part from this. The syntax error you mention in the other questions should not be present in the query above if you type it exactly as I have done. Try to use the debugger, put a breakpoint at the init of this method and then execute step by step until you hit the exception and verify at each pass the values and the strings used. One of the most important quality for a programmer is to be patient.